# Migration error to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I would like to migrate my ASP.NET Core project to Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, but I'm getting an error.

> E:\xxxxxx\projectName.xproj : error  : The imported project
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props"
>   was not found. Also, tried to find "DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" in
>   the fallback search path(s) for $(VSToolsPath) - "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0" . These search paths are
>   defined in
>   "C:\Users\mskur\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_0cd52d80\devenv.exe.config".
>   Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that
>   the file exists on disk in one of the search paths. 
>   E:\xxxxxx\projectName.xproj

Do you need something else which can help you to investigate problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Close VS, remove all `bin`, `obj`, `packages`, `artifacts`, `.vs` and other out-of-version-control folders. Remove/rollback to original files (before opening in VS2017). Delete `global.json` if you have old SDK version there. Open command prompt and run `dotnet migrate` in solution folder.

Comment: @Dmitry Should I also delete xproj file before migration?

Comment: @Dmitry I've done dotnet-migratiob but when I run app with VS 2015 I still have an windows to do migration.

Comment: You can't open migrated csproj in VS2015. You mean VS2017? Does `dotnet migrate` completed successfully?

Comment: Yes, I meant VS 2017 (sorry). The dotnet migrate process has been completed successfully

Comment: Now you should have `csproj` and do not have `xproj`. Nothing to convert anymore. Does your project opensourced/visible somewhere (github, bitbucket etc)?